# Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]' cannot be serialized

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract

I am getting following error on my server (Windows 2008 Framework 4).

*Type `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]'` cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.*

**Couple of observations:**
 * It WORKS fine with my local machine (windows 7, Framework 4.5 installed)
 * I didn't call Async methods EX: UnderWritngReportData[] uwData =    client.RetriveUnderwritingAuditReport(reportDate);
 * Having same problem with both Net.TCP and basicHttpBindings
 * Look a the error messages Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]'
   cannot be serialized.  **I called three different methods which are having three return types. but the error message is same for all the three methods**
 * I guess the error is completely misleading. I mentioned the datacontract and datamember attributes
   properly

Funding Report Error: ***Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]' cannot be serialized***. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Bording Report Error: ***Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]' cannot be serialized***. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

UW Report Error: ***Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]' cannot be serialized***. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

My WCF Contract:

```
public interface IReportService {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveFundingReport", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveFundingReportResponse")]
        FundingReportData[] RetriveFundingReport(System.DateTime Reportdate);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveFundingReport", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveFundingReportResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FundingReportData[]> RetriveFundingReportAsync(System.DateTime Reportdate);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveBordingReport", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveBordingReportResponse")]
        BordingReportData[] RetriveBordingReport(System.DateTime Reportdate);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveBordingReport", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveBordingReportResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<BordingReportData[]> RetriveBordingReportAsync(System.DateTime Reportdate);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveUnderwritingAuditReport", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveUnderwritingAuditReportResponse")]
        UnderWritngReportData[] RetriveUnderwritingAuditReport(System.DateTime Reportdate);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveUnderwritingAuditReport", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IReportService/RetriveUnderwritingAuditReportResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<UnderWritngReportData[]> RetriveUnderwritingAuditReportAsync(System.DateTime Reportdate);
    }
```

Any idea what went wrong here?!

Comment: in your local environment change the framework to .Net 4.0 and try. you may be able to reproduce it locally and debug

Comment: @Dhawalk Thanks for the quick response. I tried setting Framework 4.0 in my local and reproduce. But it still works fine. I think the given link doesn't suit my requirements. I was able to genarate the proxy and got the error when I call WCF methods from client exe. I am not calling any Async methods. Also I am confused my same exception for different methods. I cannot install .Net 4.5 on the server. I am looking for alternate ways.

Comment: You can't use Task in 4.0, and that's the reason why I pointed to the other question. the return type in that question is also Task. Hence, I believe you are wrong when you say that it worked for you in 4.0. please double check

Comment: When I try WCFTestClient from the server, i got the expected data back. So, this is definately problem with my proxy class. I didn't use Task at all !! It is just a straight call .. UnderWritngReportData[] uwData = client.RetriveUnderwritingAuditReport(reportDate);

Comment: Your OperationContract clearly has Task 
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FundingReportData[]> RetriveFundingReportAsync(System.DateTime Reportdate);

Comment: Yes I noticed that (Task) in the proxy file. Good news .... when I force my proxy not to create async methods using ** /synconly .. it works.** Circle back to the problem again. Though I am not calling the async methods, why that error happens? (BTW my client is a simple WPF form with Target framework 4.0). Also why the same error Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]' for all three methods? It will be greate to know those answers. Atleast I am able to roll on my work for now :)

Comment: I forced my client to install Framework 4.5 on our Web Server :) It works fine. So we have two soutions now. Either go for .Net 4.5 or /synconly while genarating proxy. Still a doubt pinches my thoughts ... why the same error Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FundingReportData[]]' for all three methods?